# Frequency DC voltage

Tags: dc, frequency, voltage-measurement, frequency-measurement

Maybe it is a silly question, but a microcontroller it is powered up with a voltage of 3.3 DC voltage, and we all know that the frequency of the DC voltage is 0 Hz.
Suppose that i want to generate a PWM waveform with a frequency of 100 KHz and the microcontroller frequency is 8 MHz. I know that a microcontroller have an internal crystal oscillator, but how it is possible to generate a DC voltage waveform with a frequency of 100 KHz when the frequency DC voltage is 0 Hz ?

Comment: What is *"DC voltage waveform"*?

Answer (score 4):

The question here is what is meant by DC and what is meant by AC.

There are two contexts, where DC and AC mean completely different things.

One perspective is that DC is any static voltage that doesn't change - i.e., a 0Hz signal.  AC is any voltage which changes over time.

The other perspective is that DC is any voltage that can change but remains the same polarity, and AC is any voltage which swings around 0V and goes both positive and negative.

So your PWM signal is DC in that it is between 0V and 3.3V, and never drops below 0V, but AC in that it changes voltage - it all depends on your interpretation of AC and DC.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, `frequency` is only meaningful when considering `AC analysis` where signals are changing. There is no such thing as frequency when considering `DC steady-state analysis`. *(And for the purists, there's really no such thing as DC steady-state analysis in the real world, because nothing stays the same for the age of the universe.)* So there's some confusion about terminology here.

That said, I think the real question here seems to be more like:

"**why does a PWM output have frequency, yet outputs a DC level?**".

Given:

- Microcontroller system clock frequency = 8MHz = 125nsec period
- PWM frequency = 100kHz = 10usec period
- VCC = 3.3V

**PWM (Pulse-Width Modulation)** is a type of modulation that switches a signal between logic high and logic low voltages, to generate a kind of "analogue" signal -- varying the **duty cycle** or the % of time that the signal is logic high. The signal is always either high or low (neglecting the signal rise/fall transition time), but the **average amount of time spent in the high state** is variable like an analog signal.

Inside the microcontroller, the PWM circuitry is just a counter and some flip-flops. Here's a simplified overview of how it works: In your example, the counter resets every 10usec (1 / 100kHz). Every 125nsec (0.125usec), the system clock rising edge increments the PWM counter to the next value. When the PWM counter reaches a limit (80 counts = 8MHz / 0.1MHz), the counter resets back to 0 and also sets the PWM output pin high. There is also a control register that the microcontroller's firmware writes with the duty cycle. When the PWM counter value reaches this control value, then the PWM output pin is reset low -- but the PWM counter continues counting. *(Note: I'm simplifying a little bit, not considering how the 100% duty cycle edge case is handled. Typically there's another control bit that forces 100% duty cycle, otherwise you could only get around 99% depending on implementation details.)*

A PWM frequency of 100kHz means that the PWM switches from high to low at the start of every 10usec period.

- When PWM duty cycle is 0%, the signal stays high for 0% of that 10usec period (i.e. always low).
- When PWM duty cycle is 25%, the signal stays high for 25% of that 10usec period: 2.5usec.
- When PWM duty cycle is 50%, the signal stays high for 50% of that 10usec period: 5usec.
- When PWM duty cycle is 75%, the signal stays high for 75% of that 10usec period: 7.5usec.
- When PWM duty cycle is 100%, the signal stays high for 100% of that 10usec period (i.e. always high).

**Converting a PWM signal into a DC voltage** only requires a series resistor and shunt capacitor to ground, forming a `low-pass filter`. When the PWM signal is logic high, the capacitor charges up, and when the PWM signal is logic low, the capacitor discharges. If the PWM duty cycle is 25%, then the capacitor spends 2.5usec charging up towards 3.3V, and then spends the remaining 7.5usec discharging towards 0V. This stabilizes at an average voltage which is 25% of 3.3V or 0.75V. Since the average DC offset that develops after the low-pass filter, depends on the PWM duty cycle, this is a cost-effective way to make a kind of `DAC` (Digital-to-Analog-Converter). **This isn't really a true DC level, it's an exponential charge/discharge waveform with an average value of (duty cycle * VCC).** But a sufficently large shunt capacitor can diminish the the amplitude of the charge/discharge ripple, and the waveform behaves "close enough" to a DC level for most purposes.

Even without any additional components, there will be some series resistance and parasitic capacitance that form some kind of low-pass filter -- even if not by design. And if the PWM is driving an LED (as is common for first-look demonstration projects), there's further visual low-pass filtering due to the response of the human eye -- an LED driven with a higher duty cycle looks brighter than an LED driven with a lower duty cycle.

Besides the counter/timer PWM module that is included in many popular microcontrollers, it's also possible to build a PWM from discrete components, or inside an FPGA, or with software. More precise duty-cycle control can be achieved by using a higher-resolution counter, but this requires a longer PWM period and thus slower response time.

**There are some limitations to this kind of PWM DAC technique.** The response time will be slow, taking several PWM periods. And the output impedance is determined by the series R in the low-pass filter. Furthermore, drawing any significant current out of the low-pass filter capacitor, will discharge the capacitor, changing the output value. As long as the PWM period is short enough to keep the capacitor refreshed, this can be acceptable in many applications. The initial accuracy depends on the reference voltage (3.3V power supply) and the resolution (the timer/counter that generates the PWM signal). **So it's not a very good DAC (by industrial control standards), but it's good enough for a wide variety of general-purpose work. And since it doesn't require any analog components except the final RC filter, it's very low-cost. Almost "free".**

Answer (score 0):

Read this about [Oscillators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_oscillator), then come back.

Answer (score 0):

The clock signal triggers a [counter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter) to count up from 0.

When the counter reaches a certain value, a [comparator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_comparator) comparing it with an [output compare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Output_compare) register will result in a true output, switching an output compare output high.

When the counter wraps around to 0, the output compare output switches low.

In this manner the counter wraparound (which may optionally be controlled/triggered by its own register) controls the frequency, and the output compare register controls the duty cycle.

Answer (score 0):

"PWM" means "Pulse Width Modulation".  A PWM waveform consists of short pulses of 3.3 volts DC, separated by brief periods of 0 volts.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about frequency as being a continuum that spans from 0 Hz to infinite then DC is nothing more than a special point on the left side of this continuum. If you have energy at any given frequency, there's no reason you can't change that energy to any other part(s) of the frequency spectrum. An oscillator is a basic way that you take 0 frequency energy and move it up to some higher frequency energy.

The crystal oscillator is something that converts some DC energy up to some frequency. The converse would be a rectifier with a low pass filter which would convert energy at some frequency down to near 0 Hz.

Your microcontroller converts the high frequency clock signal down to 100 kHz for your pwm by using a [frequency divider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_divider#Digital_dividers) and a counter. Ignacio Expands on that more. The energy to do so comes from the DC line.